# Find dimensions of a container passed by reference

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I wrote a following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>


using std::cin; using std::cout; using std::endl;

int DivideTwoFactorials(int m, int n)
{
    int div(1);
    while (m > n)
    {
        div *= m;
        m--;
    }
    return div;
}

int Factorial(int m)
{
    int fact(1);
    for (int i(1); i <=m; i++) fact *= i;
    return fact;
}

int BinomialCoefficient(int m, int n)
{
    return (DivideTwoFactorials(m, n) * (1./Factorial(m-n)));
}

template <typename Type>
void Modify3DContainer(Type &a, int fun(int, int), int p = 0, int q = 0)
{
    int m(a.size());
    int n(a[0].size());
    int z(a[0][0].size());

    for (int i(0); i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j(0); j < n; j++)
        {
            for (int k(0); k < z; k++)
            {
                if (a[i][j][k] == fun(p, q)) a[i][j][k] = a[i][j][k] * a[i][j][k];
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << endl << "Input dimensions of 3D container: ";
    int m, n, p;

    cin >> m >> n >> p;

    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> a(m, std::vector<std::vector<int>>(n, std::vector<int>(p)));
    cout << endl << "Input elements of 3D container: ";
    int x;
    for (int i(0); i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j(0); j < n; j++)
        {
            for (int k(0); k < p; k++)
            {
                cin >> x;
                a[i][j][k] = x;
            }
        }
    }

    Modify3DContainer(a, BinomialCoefficient, 6, 4);

    cout << endl << "Modified 3D container: " << endl << endl;

    for (int i(0); i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j(0); j < n; j++)
        {
            for (int k(0); k < p; k++)
            {
                cout << std::setw(6) << a[i][j][k];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There is one issue regarding the function "Modify3DContainer" which accepts the following parameters:

- a reference on a 3D container
- a function that returns an int and receives two int parameters
- two int parameters with default value 0.

The function is supposed to find all elements in the 3D container that are equal to return value of function defined by the second parameter when that function receives p and q as parameters, and substitute those elements with their square value.
The problem here is that function "Modify3DContainer" accepts multiple types of containers and I am not allowed to pass dimensions of the container to said function (c++ programming assignment). The function currently works only for vector of vectors of vectors by using the size() method, but it will not work for regular arrays. I tried using the sizeof operator, but it doesn't work on multidimensional vectors. Checking the type of the container with typeid could be one possible solution, but there are many combinations to check since the 3D container could, for example, be vector of vectors of deques etc.

So my question is, is there a way to find the size of passed 3D container, no matter its type?

Thank you.

Comment: Use iterators or range-for loops instead?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thank you, sir. I completely forgot about range for loops since I have been rarely required to use them. The problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to know the size then what you are looking for is [`std::size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size).  It will tell you the size of anything passed to it that is a raw array or an object that has a `size` member function.  Unfortunately it is a C++17 feature so you might not have it available in the compiler you are using.

Fortunately the mechanics for it already exist in the current standard so we can write our own like the possible implementation provided at previous link

> ```
> template <class C> 
> constexpr auto size(const C& c) -> decltype(c.size())
> {
>     return c.size();
> }
>
> template <class T, std::size_t N>
> constexpr auto size(const T (&array)[N]) noexcept
> {
>     return N;
> }
> ```

And using them in something like

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> vec(10, std::vector<std::vector<int>>(20, std::vector<int>(30, 0)));
    int arr[10][20][30];

    std::cout << size(vec) << "\t" << size(arr) << "\n";
    std::cout << size(vec[0]) << "\t" << size(arr[0]) << "\n";
    std::cout << size(vec[0][0]) << "\t" << size(arr[0][0]) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

We get

```
10  10
20  20
30  30
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6107d7fb761410a)</kbd>

---

If you do not need the size but just need to loop then you can use a [range based for loop](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6107d7fb761410a) or a regular loop and use [`std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) which works with containers and arrays.